# Android Facebook,How to Get Status ID

Tags: android

To get Facebook Friends status I have to provide status id according to Graph Api
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/status . What is the way to get status ID?

Answer (score 0):

### This will help you:

```
if (session.isOpened()) {
    // make request to the /me API
    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
    {
    // callback after Graph API response with user object

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
        if (user != null) {
            id=user.getId();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), session.getAccessToken(), 100).show();
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: This tells me my session id.But I wanted to get status of my friends Like what status they have posted on their walls? Like."Going to Dubai Feeling excited."